# Dynamic Properties file in Jenkins for injecting Env variables

Tags: jenkins

So this is my entire Use case:
I have a parameterized build job which accepts file parameters. After the build I need to send a mail with that file and the size of the file. For this, I'm trying to add the name and size of the file as an Env variable using EnvInject Plugin. 
But EnvInject is in the Build Environment step. The file parameter gets stored in the Workspace of the build only in the Build step, not in Build environment. So, there will be an error like File not found.

Due to which, I'm trying a crooked way of defining a properties file somewhere on my local system.I'm mentioning this properties file in "Properties File Path" of Inject Environment variables. In the build step I'm adding FOO=BAR and other values in the file so that I can use those values as my env variables down the line, like when I configure my e-mail template in Post Build Actions.

Can this process be done easily? I was initially making the properties file in JENKINS_HOME. I just got to know that I'm not allowed to do that as in master-agent architecture, JENKINS_HOME will be different and build will fail.

PS-1. The workspace gets deleted after every build
2. Any other plugins which can be used? If possible, please suggest without installing some new plugin as I'm not Jenkins admin

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, what file path are you running your job with? is the file in the workspace? how does it get there? are you pulling from source control? File Parameter is supposed to be a workspace relative path, it means it should exist within your workspace.
Why not use a string parameter instead?

Comment: I am receiving the file from the parameters and yes, it should be copied into my workspace. But from what I can see, it gets copied in the build step, not build-environment where I'm injecting variables.

Comment: I think I got it now, why not use EnvInject plugin as a build step instead of build-environment?

Comment: If I run a groovy script in the "Evaluated Groovy script" to see the files in the workspace, it comes up empty. But while in the build step, a script to see the files in the workspace shows the newly added file.

Comment: Do you mean "Inject Environment variables" in the build step? That requires a properties file locally right?

Comment: you don't have to use a properties file, you can use `Properties Content` instead with key value pairs (i.e. Variable=Value)

Answer (score 0):

**One way of solving this problem is by creating 3 different jobs as follows -**

**job 1** --> should call below 2 jobs(job 2 & job 3)
    job 2: 
        Build --> Trigger/call builds on other projects --> job 2(block until the triggerred projects finish their builds)
        select"Build on the same node" from Add Parameters.
    job 3: 
        Build --> Trigger/call builds on other projects --> job 2(block until the triggerred projects finish their builds)
        select"Build on the same node" from Add Parameters.

**Job 2** (Create this job as follows):
    Execution API --> using "GET_FILE" option you can download the required details on to the current working directory of your job. 
    Execute shell --> 
        now within "Execute Shell", download "consoleText" using wget command. 
        process the "consoleText" using unix command prepare a key-value pairs and store it under /tmp folder. i.e. "/tmp/env.prop"

**Job 3** (Create this job as follows):
    Bindings: 
        select "Inject environment variable to the build process" and under 'Properties File Path' enter "/tmp/env.prop"
        now you can use the variable which you created in Job2 in the current job without any issue.

please note that it is important to select "Build on the same node" in Job 1, because this will preserve the data and it allows other jobs to access this information.

Let me know if its not clear.